# Problem with Views accordion if using multiple accordions on same page

Tags: views, javascript, navigation

I'm using the views accordion module and it's working really well on this D7 site.

However, a client has now requested that two different lists are displayed on one page. I've set them both to be blocks and they appear ok - but the first of the two lists doesn't seem to get the appropriate Javascript treatment and the headings are not clickable/body does not expand.

I have raised a support request to the developers - but in the meantime anyone here have any suggestions?

Comment: In case not clear - the 2nd of the two lists works absolutely fine, so suspecting a Javascript issue.

Comment: Open up the javascript console in your browser and see if it outputs any errors.

Comment: No errors - it seems to be doing at least part of the work, just not attaching the on-click handler to the first view's headings once the content is hidden.